# Firebase skipped through my code and not reading data in swift

Tags: ios, swift

I tried to read data from Firebase without signing in and I couldn't retrieve any data at all. Xcode just skip right over where I got the reading set up. The code work fine with I have the users set up and sign in but it won't work if I don't have the user sign in.

```
   //getting data
    DataService.ds.REF_QUESTIONS.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshots) in
        self.data.removeAll(keepingCapacity: true)
        if let snapshot = snapshots.children.allObjects as? [DataSnapshot] {
            for snap in snapshot {
                if let questionsDict = snap.value as? String {
                    self.data.append(questionsDict)
                }
            }

            //generate random question and make sure it is not repeat in the past 25 questions
            var random:UInt32 = arc4random_uniform(UInt32(self.data.count))
            while self.previousquestion.contains(Int(random)) {
                random = arc4random_uniform(UInt32(self.data.count))
            }
            self.previousquestion.remove(at: 0)
            self.previousquestion.append(Int(random))

            //Display data if it exist
            if let list: [String] = (self.data[Int(random)].components(separatedBy: ";")) {
            //if let list: [String] = (self.data[100].components(separatedBy: ";")) {
                self.questions.text = list[0]
                self.questions.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.center
                self.button1.setTitle(list[1], for: .normal)
                self.button1.titleLabel?.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.center
                self.button2.setTitle(list[2], for: .normal)
                self.button2.titleLabel?.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.center
                self.button3.setTitle(list[3], for: .normal)
                self.button3.titleLabel?.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.center
                self.button4.setTitle(list[4], for: .normal)
                self.button4.titleLabel?.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.center
                self.answer = list[5]
                self.winString = list[6]
                self.scoreLbl.text = String(self.score)
                self.coinLbl.text = String(self.coins)
            }
        }            
    })

    //display user highest score
    DataService.ds.REF_USERS.observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in
        if let snapshot = snapshot.children.allObjects as? [DataSnapshot] {
            for snap in snapshot {

                if snap.key == String((Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid)!)! {
                    if let userDict = snap.value as? Dictionary<String, Any> {
                        if let _ = userDict["highest_score"] {
                            self.chancesLbl.text = String(describing: userDict["highest_score"]!)
                            if self.score >= ((userDict["highest_score"]) as? Int)! {
                                DataService.ds.REF_CURRENT_USER.child("highest_score").setValue(self.score)
                            }
                        } else {
                            DataService.ds.REF_CURRENT_USER.child("highest_score").setValue(0)
                        }
                    }
                }

            }
        }
    })
```

If I comment out the user part then the whole getting data block will not work.

Any input is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you checked your Firebase rules to make sure users not signed in can read data?

Comment: Wherever you have `if` statements, you might want to add `else` and print out what's happening.

Comment: How do I check the firebase rule?